How to remove all accidentally synced text messages from iPhone and MacBook
I temporarily signed in with my Apple development account on a personal iPhone, which I also use to sign into a second iPhone (without a SIM) and a MacBook. Later, I signed out from the personal iPhone but realised that all my text messages in it ended up on the development iCloud, the second iPhone, and the MacBook, which is not what I wanted! I would like to keep those two accounts and devices separate.
I turned off text message sync on the second iPhone and instructed it to delete all text messages from iCloud, but saw no option to erase them from iPhone as well. They appear to have been deleted from iCloud. However, these text messages still appear on the second iPhone and the MacBook, and there are lots of them, accumulated over years.
Of course I can select those text messages one by one and delete them manually from the second iPhone and MacBook. As a last resort, I could also try a factory reset on iPhone, but would not like to do that on the MacBook because I spent days already setting it up. I'm wondering if there is a proper or faster way to do this? Thank you!
